# Deleting a row with a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have a table of instructors with a column FileId that corresponds to a file in the Files table. When he/she replaces a file I want to be able to go and delete the old one. I DO NOT want to delete the Instructor entry, just the file. When I edited the relationship so that it would allow cascades on update and delete and then I ran the stored proc below it deleted the Instructor entry, which is not the desired effect, please let me know if you have any suggestions. 
Thanks for your help

```
   ALTER PROC [dbo].[Files_DeleteByInstructorFileId]
   @Id int,
   @FileId int = NULL

   as 
   begin

   /*

   EXECUTE [dbo].[Files_DeleteByInstructorFileId] 162

   */

    Update [dbo].[Instructors] SET 

        FileId = @FileId
       WHERE @Id = Id

       DELETE f FROM [dbo].[Files] f
        JOIN [dbo].[Instructors] ins
        ON ins.FileId = f.Id

       WHERE ins.Id = @Id


   END
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure your referenced column(foreign key constraint) is set as CASCADE on delete and update.
like

```
CONSTRAINT `job_status_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`jobseeker_id`)
 REFERENCES `jobseeker` (`jobseeker_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: So I'm very new to SQL just learning, so you're saying that after updating the relationship design I should add what you wrote above to the stored procedure instead of the delete logic that I'm using?

Comment: You can write the same query to delete a row, But when you are making foreign key then by default it's RESTRICTED or NO ACTION on delete/update. now you have to change it into CASCADE then it will allow to delete referenced column . You can see your current action by using query SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME

Comment: Hi again so when I tried this what ended up happening is that the entire Instructor entry was deleted. I am trying to just delete the file from the file table that corresponds to that particular instructor, but not delete the instructor if that makes any sense...

Comment: Obviously a delete query will delete whole row not a single value. If you want to delete a single value then it means you want to update a column value so use Update instead of DELETE query.  And set whatever you want, it will replace the previous  one.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I first declared a variable equal to the Instructor's fileId, then I set the fileId to null so that I could delete the file and not be restricted by the foreign key constraint, then I used the variable to find the correct file to delete. If there's other ways of doing this I'd still be interested...

```
DECLARE @FileIdNumber int
SELECT @FileIdNumber = [dbo].[Instructors].[FileId]
FROM [dbo].[Instructors]
WHERE [dbo].[Instructors].[Id] = @Id

Update [dbo].[Instructors] SET 

FileId = @FileId
WHERE @Id = Id

DELETE f FROM [dbo].[Files] f
WHERE f.Id = @FileIdNumber
```